# Prisma DB seeding error within Digital Ocean - how to solve the waiting pid 155 error

Tags: typescript, digital-ocean, prisma, seeding

having a seeding error when running prisma db in digital ocean.  What are the proper steps to resolve this issue?
Error message: npx prisma db seed
Running seed comand : //ts-node src/prisma/seeds/seed.ts
waiting on pid 155 : waiting on pid 155 in sandbox "XXXXX sandbox # displayed here"
urpc method "containerManager.waitpid" Failed EOF

This issue didn't happen before and suddenly appeared 2 days ago. We have checked line by line internally and checked existing stack exchange errors but they are different.

Comment: Can you share detailed logs for this error?

Comment: Hi! Was able to debug. We had the error since the prisma seeding takes up so much memory to run. We were on $10 and had downgraded to the $5. The error only happened after the downgrade. It errored due to reaching 80% memory on $5. Post moving back to $10 , it’s resolved.

Comment: I'm glad this is resolved. Thank you for the information. It's really helpful

Comment: Also, worth noting is that you cannot use SQLite in DO App Platform due to the nature of ephemeral container deployments (in Droplets it works fine).